# Navbar Active won't change when clicking to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Navbar is being buggy. I wish to have the activate tab change as a user goes through the different pages.

I am using a base template so I don't want to reproduce the navbar html/css for every single page so I believe javascript is the answer to my issue here.

I've attempted to use some Jquery from another question, it unfortunately created a separate problem, I am not well versed with Jquery so I found it very difficult to fix the issue.

This is the HTML

```
            <div class="container-fluid">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/sidespacer.png' %}"></a>

                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">

                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/Spaces">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Spaces/space">Spaces</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Spaces/pricing">Prices</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/Spaces/howitworks">How it Works</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out
                                {{user.username}}</a></li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>

                    </div>

            </div>

    </nav>
```

This is the current Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".nav-item" ).bind( "click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clickedItem = $( this );
        $( ".nav-item" ).each( function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
        });
        clickedItem.addClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

The Jquery lets the activate state change but prevents the user being directed to the link.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: your code is little confusing, why you used `event.preventDefault();` for `li`? because `".nav-item"` class is attached to `li` only and li doesn't have click behaviour by default

Comment: honestly I have such a limited understanding of jquery that it's difficult for me to appreciate what you're saying. If you have a solution please share it below and explain as much as you can (explain it like i'm 5 :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used python in the end to solve this issue, example below.

```
<li class="nav-item {% if request.path == index_url %}active{% endif %}" id="HomeNav"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ index_url }}">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const linkLi = $( ".nav-item" );
    const linkAnchor = $( ".nav-item a" ); // anchor is require to prevent for not to direct
    linkAnchor.bind( "click", function(event) {
        var clickedItem = $( this ).parent("li:first");
        linkLi.each( function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
        });
        clickedItem.addClass( "active" );
    });
   $( ".nav-item a[href$='"+window.location.pathname+"']" ).parent("li:first").addClass("active"); 
});
```

see this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ova8nwtz/1/))

Comment: This has the same issue where the active nav link does change but it will not take the user to the page clicked on.

Comment: Unfortunately it is now linking properly but not changing the active state :S

Comment: can you please check and confirm from your browser console is `active` class change on `li`?